# return dataset from .net service and use data into android

Tags: android, dataset

Is there any way to extract data from dataset which contains records 
I want to call .net webservice using android but its return dataset
so how to handle dataset?

Answer (score 1):

it's turkish but maybe it helps you bro check it. http://aaarkonusurum.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-ile-dataset-donen-bir-net.html